# How to test database access code

Tags: database, testing

I have a db layer. And I want to test db CRUD results
I want every single test to be independent, so I just create tables in setUp(), and drop all tables in tearDown(). So is there any good way to test db access independently? I mean I don't need to drop all tables in every test

Comment: Why not `delete from` the table in tearDown or setUp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of approaches.

1. You can delete all the data after the each test by using "DELETE" statement. As far as I know, deletes are slow) so its less preferable approach.
2. You can truncate the tables after each test, so that they will be empty.
3. (My Favorite one) Open a transaction before each test, and *rollback* it after the test finishes (even successfully!). This way you'll preserve the state in db as it was before the test.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks man! You and @k3b both give me good advices, so it's hard for me to choose which one as the answer! Finally I choose yours because you give me three approaches...

Answer (score 1):

You can do the database tests within a database transaction that will be rolled back after the test.

For example in java / spring you can use the 
[TestContext framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx) that will create and roll back a transaction for each test.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I don't realize using transaction before.